# How to relaunch running application

Tags: c#

i am working on an win mobile application . I am running application in background using

```
e.Cancle = true;
```

Now i need to relaunch same instance of that application so that i can off that  application .

can any one tell me ... how to do this?

Comment: What? could you rewrite the question in a clearer way?

Comment: is the thing that stops the application another application. or does the application need to be able to restart itself?

Comment: Akrant - I'm confused by this sentence, it doesn't make sense.  "Now i need to relaunch that application so that i can stop running application."  I think I understand that the application you've written is running in the background, now are you trying to figure out how to send it a message telling it to restart?

Comment: @stephbu ...  yeah thats what i mean .. sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application needs to restart itself this may help you :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart.aspx

You don't actually need to be running a winforms application for this to work - you just need to make sure the System.Windows.Forms DLL is present.

PS. i couldn't get this working for WPF - but I don't actually remember the exact reason right now

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1) Stop application(Kill process) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx or Exit application http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit(v=vs.71).aspx

2) Run application again(Start process) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.71).aspx

Also you may use `Restart` method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart.aspx

Which way you will choose depends no the your particular situation.

Comment: `Application.Restart` is present before .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

This might do it.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
Close();
```